# Regex with OR statement to check similar cases

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I've been roaming through the Regex wiki and a few other regex tutorials on how to properly write an OR statement inside a regex, but no luck so far. Basically I am checking a string such as this (example):

`if (val === 7)` and `if (7 === val)`.

The current regex successfully passes any user code with the first string `(val === 7)`, but fails the second string.

The original regex looks like such:

`/val\\s*===\\s*\\d+/g`

My work-in-progress revision of the regex looks like:

`/(val|s*)\\s*===\\(s*|val)\\d+/g`

Basically, I was trying to include an OR statement inside the regex to check both cases, but I'm stumped. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me some advice? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pipe symbol | can be used as the or statement between groups

Comment: how about `/(val\\s*===\\s*\\d+)|(\\d+\\s*===\\s*val)/g`

Comment: @mido That was it! I didn't realize I could put that much "regex" in between the pipe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like said in comments, you could solve the issue by:

```
/(val\\s*===\\s*\\d+)|(\\d+\\s*===\\s*val)/g
```

the `|` checks between either of the matching groups.